# $lookup in Mongodb return empty array

Tags: mongodb

I am working on a mongodb database project. I have two collections: "user" and "comments". I want to combine some info from "user" to "comments" using $lookup.

Here is my "user" collection:

```
db.user.insert(
[
    { user_id: 1, fname: "D", lname: "Lei", email: "d@m.edu" },
    { user_id: 2, fname: "R", lname: "Wick", email: "rn@m.edu" },
    { user_id: 3, fname: "B", lname: "Elfs", email: "bs@m.edu" },
    { user_id: 4, fname: "A", lname: "Losh", email: "a@me.edu" },
    { user_id: 5, fname: "T", lname: "Ph", email: "p_thi@m.edu" }

]
)
```

Here is "comments" collection:

```
db.comments.insert(
[
{blog_ID: 37, user_ID: 4, texts: 'comment ...', date_posted: '2016-1-1'},
{blog_ID: 3, user_ID: 4, texts: 'comment ...', date_posted: '2009-7-4'},
{blog_ID: 15, user_ID: 3, texts: 'comment ...', date_posted: '2017-6-4'},
{blog_ID: 4, user_ID: 4, texts: 'comment ...', date_posted: '2012-3-11'},
{blog_ID: 38, user_ID: 5, texts: 'comment ...', date_posted: '2005-11-6'},
{blog_ID: 2, user_ID: 1, texts: 'comment ...', date_posted: '2011-10-11'},
{blog_ID: 46, user_ID: 4, texts: 'comment ...', date_posted: '2014-12-13'},
{blog_ID: 31, user_ID: 2, texts: 'comment ...', date_posted: '2012-11-26'},
{blog_ID: 26, user_ID: 3, texts: 'comment ...', date_posted: '2006-10-28'},
{blog_ID: 47, user_ID: 3, texts: 'comment ...', date_posted: '2018-1-15' }
]
)
```

Here is my query:

```
   db.comments.aggregate([

    {$match: {user_ID:4}},        
    {$group: {_id:"$user_ID", count:{$sum:1}}},
    {$lookup:{
                from: "user",
                localField: "user_ID",
                foreignField: "user_id",
                as: "combine"
            }
     }


])
```

The "combine" array is empty:

[image]

Comment: I think you mean `user_ID` and `user_id` because those are the only data the two have in common. Best to put a pot of coffee on.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I will get an empty "combine" array if I use $match and $group. Without those, my query will return a "comments" collection with "combine" array as expected. (I just edited my question to reflect what I actually intended to ask).

Answer (score 1):

The second stage of your pipeline (`$group` stage) is replacing the original `user_ID` field with `_id` field. So you have to use `_id` as the `localField` in your `$lookup` stage:

```
db.comments.aggregate([
    {$match: {user_ID:4}},        
    {$group: {_id:"$user_ID", count:{$sum:1}}},
    {$lookup:{
                from: "user",
                localField: "_id",
                foreignField: "user_id",
                as: "combine"
            }
     }
])
```

Comment: Ooooh. Your explanation solved my problem. Thank you! :D